# Firebase project url returns a 404 after Vercel app successfully authenticates using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, vercel, sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit app that uses Firebase for authentication and for Cloud Firestore. Running the app locally with the Firebase emulator, everything works. When deploying with Vercel, I have the server configured to use the Firebase service account, and the client has the client config as provided by Firesbase.

When I run the app for real, deployed via Vercel, I get the following behavior.

1. When I use "sign in with google" functionality within my app, the app redirects to Google account selection and lets me select my google account
2. Checking the Firebase console, I see that I was successfully created within Authentication tab.
3. However, the Vercel app immediately bounces me back to my log-in screen. Examining the client console within Chrome I see the following error:

> singletons-a6a7384f.js:259  GET https://my-firebase-project.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/init.json 404 (Not Found)

I can confirm that the project name `my-firebase-project` in the url is correct and matches what is provided in the Firebase console as well as the config generated by Firebase.

In my package.json I am using

```
                "firebase": "9.0.1",
                "firebase-admin": "^9.10.0",
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this?